# Unable to load spring.data application.properties in Spring WebFlux

Tags: spring-data, spring-webflux

I'm unable to load `spring.data` configuration `from application.properties` in Spring WebFlux
Here's what I added in `application.properties`

```
  spring.data.web.pageable.default-page-size=2
  spring.data.web.pageable.max-page-size=2147483647
```

The same properties work in Spring MVC
Inside `SpringDataWebAutoConfiguration`, there is `@ConditionalOnClass({PageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolver.class, WebMvcConfigurer.class})` which may be the cause why it's not loaded in Spring WebFlux because it doens't have `WebMvcConfigurer`

Is it the problem?
How to load the properties in WebFlux?

Comment: why do you need pagable in WebFlux, it makes no sense to have it

Comment: Because I need to use pagination. If using Pageable doesn't make sense, what should I use in WebFlux?

Answer (score 1):

In Spring Webflux there is currently no customization available of the `ReactivePageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolver` with properties but you can customize it via `WebFluxConfigurer`.

```
@Configuration
class WebFluxConfiguration implements WebFluxConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void configureArgumentResolvers(ArgumentResolverConfigurer configurer) {
        var pageableResolver = new ReactivePageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolver();

        pageableResolver.setMaxPageSize(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
        pageableResolver.setFallbackPageable(PageRequest.of(0, 2));

        configurer.addCustomResolver(pageableResolver);
    }
}
```

You could also create your own properties binding with [Configuration Properties](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-external-config-typesafe-configuration-properties) now and pass the values to the setters.